# SQLite: select multiple rows referencing the same foreign key

Tags: java, sqlite

I am quite the beginner in SQLite and I have two simple tables as follow:

1. `contact` with an id as **PK** and a name as **TEXT**
2. `phoneNumber` with an id as **PK**, a contactId as an **FK to contact.id** and a number as **TEXT**

Simply put, a contact can have multiple phone numbers. Each phoneNumber entry / row has a constraint by referencing the contact'd id as a foreign key.

I wish to select all contacts and their phone numbers. So I'd imagine, for each row in my `resultSet`, I have

1. the contact's unique ID
2. the contact's name
3. an array of the contact's phone numbers

Is there a way to have this with one query, maybe coupled with a subquery ? Otherwise I have to make two statements, one to get all contacts, and one per contact to get their respective phone numbers.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can live with having all the contacts phone numbers as a comma separated list, then here is one option:

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.number) AS numbers
FROM contact c
LEFT JOIN phoneNumber p
    ON c.id = p.contactId
GROUP BY
    c.id, c.name;
```

Comment: This seems to work just nice ! I understand now why everything must stand within one row, so we use GROUP_CONCAT to have multiple entries (rows) inside one column. I'll make more tests and soon validate your answer. Many thanks !